# How to pass client properties to a knap command

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a snapshot from a Kafka cluster using knap.
How can include client properties like security.protocol or ssl.keystore.location on a knap command like this "ksnap backup -b kafka.internal.cloudapp.net:9092 -t t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 -d ./backupDir

Current error is "socket disconnected"

Answer (score 0):

> include client properties like security.protocol or ssl.keystore.location

You can't. The source-code hard-codes specific properties that cannot be extended.

https://github.com/EclipseTrading/ksnap/blob/master/ksnap/reader/kafka_python.py#L19-L26